# Javascript: Find modified object by DOM event

Tags: javascript, web, dom

I want to find one or more objects modified after clicking on an element in a web page. This but "reverse engineering" meaning I do not know the objects or the properties.

For example: on a YouTube video when clicking on the mute button the `yt.player.utils.videoElement_.muted` is modified from `false`to `true`.

I want to know if a general technique could be applied independently of the website and the objects.

Edit: I do not want to track only DOM modification as proposed by @Yogi, but I want to track all JS object modification done by an event (which is not necessarily DOM modification).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect changes in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)

Comment: @Yogi No, the question you linked is about modification of the DOM. In my case I do not modify the DOM. It is a DOM event that modify a JS Object. I tried the 3 firsts solutions with the example in the question and nothing triggered as (sadly) expected.

Comment: Not possible.  There are no generic solutions that would allow you to observe objects over which you have no control and know nothing about, i.e., properties and methods.